# Como hacer inserción de todos los registros concatenados de una tabla a otra

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Buenas tengo esa duda no se como hacer concatenación de 2 tablas las cuales son una que yo cree llamada TEST y la otra EMPLOYEE(ya creada en el esquema HR), también tenia otra duda de como modificar una tabla ya creada(TEST) añadiendo una columna mas, y la ultima crear una tabla(TEST1) basado con select de otra tabla de EMPLOYEE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por favor revisa

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/tables/alter_table.php

y por ultimo una tabla(TEST1) basado con select de otra tabla de EMPLOYEE.

```
create table test as (select * from employee);
```